# Rotate a boundingBox by a given angle

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I'm working with output from Azure Computer Vision Read API. The output has a boundingBox and angle of the page. I need to rotate the points in boundingBox.

A sample boundingBox is : "boundingBox": [
2.4533,
10.6901,
2.6147,
10.6901,
2.6147,
10.8193,
2.4533,
10.8193
], And the angle is in degrees-180 to 180.

I need to rotate the points in the bounding box in order to feel similar to the output from a page which has 0 degree.My environment is python.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
def rotate(point, origin, degrees):
    radians = np.deg2rad(degrees)
    x,y = point
    offset_x, offset_y = origin
    adjusted_x = (x - offset_x)
    adjusted_y = (y - offset_y)
    cos_rad = np.cos(radians)
    sin_rad = np.sin(radians)
    qx = offset_x + cos_rad * adjusted_x + sin_rad * adjusted_y
    qy = offset_y + -sin_rad * adjusted_x + cos_rad * adjusted_y
    return qx, qy
def correctAngle(analysis):
    for page in analysis["analyzeResult"]["readResults"]:
        if page["angle"] !=0:
            for line in page['lines']:
                bBox= line['boundingBox']
                for ind in range (0, 7, 2):
                    bBox[ind],bBox[ind+1]=rotate((bBox[ind],bBox[ind+1]),(0,0),page["angle"])
                line['boundingBox']=bBox
    return analysis
```

Comment: Why is the origin bottom left? (0,0)? The documentation says center of image. `the center of the original image`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models.ocrresult?view=azure-python